# Hibernate exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, classpath, drivers

My Java project when I run it on local server (localhost:8080) is throwing an error: 
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver**

This error is thrown when Hibernate is trying to connect to Oracle database on

```
 session = PersistenceManager.sessionFactory().openSession();
```

When I deploy app to Production or Test server there is no problem.
In order to troubleshoot I need to make it work on my local machine. **What am I missing?**

First I thought that Oracle drivers are missing so I downloaded **classes12.jar** and added it to **Java Build Path > Libraries**. That didn't help. I am still getting same error.

Thanks

Comment: The Java Build path is the classpath used to compile your Java code. It's not the same thing as the classpath used to run the deployed application. If it's a web app, the jar should be in the appserver classpath, or in the war's WEB-INF/lib directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be on your build path but is it on the classpath of your app server ?

Comment: Thanks. It was not. I copied ojdbc14.jar from lib folder from Test server to lib folder on my local machine and everything works now.

Answer (score 2):

`ojdbc6.jar` is the jar for the oracle jdbc driver - make sure it's on the classpath